# Error getting data from a json. Expected a value type int, but got one of type String

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm trying to redirect the user to a page from the return of a json. If the json is empty, it goes to one page, if it sees information in the json, it goes to another.

The redirect I do like this:

```
onPressed: () async {
                              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                var return = await widget
                                    .producer
                                    .searchProducer(data.text);

                                if (return.isEmpty) {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            const Page1()),
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              const Page2()));
                                }
                              }
                            },
```

And the service.dart

```
class producer {
  Future<List<Producer>> searchProducer(data) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse(BaseUrl.baseUrl + 'api/producer/searchProducer/$data'));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        List<Producer> list = parseProducer(response.body);
        return list;
      } else {
        throw Exception("Error");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e.toString());
    }
  }

  static List<Producer> parseProducer(String responseBody) {
    final parsed =
        json.decode(responseBody.toString()).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<Producer>((json) => Producer.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
}
```

When the json is empty, there are no errors. But if the array has information I'm getting the error:

> Error: Exception: Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'

I appreciate if anyone helps analyze this!

Comment: The error is most definitely inside this function `Producer.fromJson()`. Could you post the code for that please?

Answer (score 0):

There must be error inside your model class recheck that , the error is due to the type of the varible match it with your response .